# How do I redirect a user to a route when a certain Redux action is dispatched?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I have a React + Redux + React Router web app that uses websockets for communication with the backend server.

Let's say a user is halfway through using the app and has left their computer idle for several hours. This will cause their session to expire.

As such then backend will send down a message saying `SESSION_EXPIRED` to the client.

I want to be able to redirect the user to another route, `/login`, so the user can log in again when this happens.

However I can't figure out how to do the redirection. I already have my actions and reducers set up so they are updating the store correctly. There is a boolean in the my store named `loggedIn: true|false`.

Is there any way I can have something that observes when the `loggedIn` state changes to `false` and then redirects the user to log-in automatically?

Answer (score 3):

You could have a redux middleware which can do the redirect.

All the middlewares will be called with every action and have access to the state.
For more info: http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in one of two ways:

1st option:

The state has a router which you could use to navigate ([using the push method](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#pushpathorloc)) when you get the event from the backend that the session has expired.

2nd option:

Use a root wrapper component which monitors the state and renders the login for if the session has expired otherwise it renders what it should render.

Something like (using redux and react-redux in example):

```
class Root extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { isLoggedIn } = this.props;
        return (
            isLoggedIn ? {this.props.children} : <Login />
        );
    }
}

export default connect((state) => ({ isLoggedIn: state.isLoggedIn }))(Root);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions here:

1. You could import the instantiated router instance into your reducer file and push to a new route from there.
2. You could simply push to a logout route using location.href and automatically react-router will handle the route change. On that logout route you could have an onEnter handler which handles the business logic for logging out.

Hope this helps.